# Discord.js Execute a Command Within Another Command

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am building a Discord bot, V12. I am now building a help command, with an embed and reaction emoji's. Here is a sample of my code:

```
if (reaction.emoji.name === RulesEmoji) {
   await message.channel.send("Test1");
}
```

It now sends a message when you react, but I want it to execute another file. Something like:

```
if (reaction.emoji.name === RulesEmoji) {
   await execute("./otherfile.js");
}
```

So does someone know how to execute another file in my commands folder within a command?

Comment: What is the structure of the command file?

Comment: What do you mean by structure?

Answer (score 1):

Create a function that handles it for you

```js
async function execute(file, ...args) {
  const f = require(file)
  if (!f) throw new Error("Invalid file")
  return f.execute(...args)
}
```

This assumes that the files look like this:

```js
module.exports = {
  async execute(reaction) {
    // execute function
  }
}
```

Execute with this:

```js
await execute("./otherfile.js", reaction)
```